# What is the average value of $y=x^2\sqrt{x^3+1}$ on the interval $(0,2)$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I know the average value formula is $$\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)\;dx$$

I have no problem plugging in 0 and 2 for a and b respectively. I think i'm struggling actually taking the integral.

Comment: That formula is incorrect. You should have $b-a$ in the denominator out front, because that is the length of the interval $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $u=x^3+1$ to get $$\int x^2\sqrt{x^3+1}\; dx=\frac{1}{3}\int\sqrt{u}\;du$$ which is much easier...

Comment: Why not let $u = x^3 + 1$?

Comment: Can you go through what you would do after substituting

Comment: Amzoti is right, let $u=x^3+1$ then $du/dx=3x^2$. Rearrange to get $dx = du/(3x^2)$. Now substitute this back into the integral, $\int x^2\sqrt{x^3+1}dx=\int x^2\sqrt{u} du/(3x^2)$. The $x^2$ terms cancel leaving you with $\frac{1}{3}\int u^{1/2} du$ which I assume you can handle.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int^2_0\dfrac{x^2\sqrt{x^3+1}}{2-0}\mathrm{d}x=\dfrac{1}{3}\int^2_0\dfrac{3x^2\sqrt{x^3+1}}{2-0}\mathrm{d}x=\\ \dfrac{1}{3}\int^2_0\dfrac{\sqrt{x^3+1}}{2-0}\mathrm{d}\left(x^3+1\right)=\left.\dfrac{1}{6}\dfrac{2({x^3+1})^{3/2}}{3}\right|^2_0$$
Just curious - is this from a practice AP test? I think I've seen this very same problem before...

Comment: Yes it is! What did you do with the $x^2$ value to make the one third and $3x^2$? Then where did the $3x^2$ go in the first equation of the second line. I'm just missing some big concept here I think.

Comment: @user142962 $$x^2=\dfrac{1}{3}3x^2$$And $$\mathrm{d}(x^3+1)=\mathrm{d}x^3+\mathrm{d}1=3x^2+0=3x^2$$

Comment: Why are you changing $x^2$ in the first place at all? why aren't we just taking the anti derivative to get $\frac{1}{3}x^3$

Comment: @user142962 Why substitute $u=x^3+1,\mathrm{d}u=3x^2$? It makes it easier to calculate, especially on the part of the AP test which forbids the use of a calculator.

Comment: @user142962 Also, how would you calculate the integral without $u$-substitution?

Answer (score 0):

here is an alternative method to substitution (actually its the same method, just arranged a bit differently).

$$\frac{1}{2-0}\int^2_0 x^2\sqrt{x^3+1}dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int^2_0 x^2\sqrt{x^3+1} dx\cdot\frac{d(x^3+1)/dx}{d(x^3+1)/dx}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int^2_0 x^2\sqrt{x^3+1}\cdot\frac{d(x^3+1)}{3x^2}$$
$$=\frac{1}{6}\int^2_0\sqrt{x^3+1} d(x^3+1)$$
now we substitute $u=x^3+1$ and $du=d(x^3+1)$
$$=\frac{1}{6}\int^9_1\sqrt{u} du=\frac{1}{6}\bigg(\frac{2}{3} u^{3/2} \bigg)\bigg|_1^9$$